# TimeMachine backup to shared windows drive via SMB?

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, windows, smb

I am trying to figure out how to reliably back up my 2013 MacBook pro to my Windows 7 desktop, living on the same network. The Windows machine is hardwired and the MacBook is connected via WiFi.

- The windows PC has a shared folder, named "MBP-TimeMachine".
- I created a `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` disk image on my MacBook Pro and copied it over to the "MBP-TimeMachine" directory.
- Using the app [AutoMounter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automounter/id1160435653?mt=12), I have my MacBook successfully connecting to my Windows share on login.

I can get the image mounted, and time machine detects it, but when I begin backup, it gets to ~400-500mb backed up before the image just randomly unmounts and I'm not sure why?

Any tips on why the image seems to unmount? Is there a better/easier/more reliable way to accomplish this?

EDIT: this is the guide I followed for configuring the network share / image. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-nas-windows-share-time-machine-backup/

Comment: We'd need to see logs to understand why it's suddenly dying. Could be the network connection, the protocol, macOS getting unhappy about the non-standard set up, issues with file links.. any logs from either side, but especially the client side at the time of failure would go a long way.